# Formulation of a vector field

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis

Let $V=y\,\partial/\partial x+x\,\partial/\partial y$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't understand about how the vector field $V$ is defined. For example how do we map a specific point (vector) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let say $(2,1)$, to $T(\mathbb{R}^2)$ using the given formula?

Comment: It is very common in manifold theory to identify directional (partial) derivatives with vectors.  In standard notation, this vector field would be the vector $\langle y,x\rangle$ at the point $(x,y)$.  This notation can be found in basic introductory books on manifold theory.  Some standard references are [Lee's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387217529) and [Tu's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441973993).

Comment: The relationship between directional derivatives and vectors is that the directional derivative is taken in the direction of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

A vector field is a section of the tangent bundle.  In other words,
$$
V:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow T(\mathbb{R}^2)
$$
such that for all $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $V(p)=V_p\in T_p(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
In other words, for all points $p$, the vector field describes a tangent vector *in the tangent space at that point*.

Therefore, your $V$ is a general rule that describes how to determine a tangent vector for each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $p=(1,2)$.  Then, using your definition, 
$$
V(p)=V_p=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p+2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_p.
$$
Here, you substitute the values for $p$ as the coefficients of the generators of the basis elements of the tangent space.  Observe that $V(p)=V_p\in T_p(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: After consulting to Tu's book, the notation $V=y\,\partial/\partial x+x\,\partial/\partial y$ merely just means $V(x,y)=(y,x)$.